# Deploying angular application with aws-cdk on github actions

Tags: github-actions, aws-cdk

I am not much of devops person so looking for some help. I have tried a few different things here. So I have a single AWS account which I created access tokens for with correct permissions and am looking to have github actions build and deploy this pretty small angular app into an S3 bucket

```
name: Deployment

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  workflow_dispatch:
env:
  AWS_ACCOUNT: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCOUNT }}

jobs:
  build:
    name: Build Angular project
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Setup Node.js
        uses: actions/setup-node@v2
        with:
          node-version: "16.x"
          registry-url: "https://npm.pkg.github.com"
          cache: "npm"

      - name: Compile client code
        run: |
          npm ci
          npm run build
          rm -f dist/*.map
          cd ./cdk
          npm ci
          cd ..

      - name: Upload build artifact
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: build
          path: |
            ${{ inputs.ng_directory }}/dist
            ${{ inputs.ng_directory }}/src/configs
          retention-days: 1

      - name: cdk bootstrap
        uses: youyo/aws-cdk-github-actions@v2.1.1
        with:
          cdk_subcommand: "bootstrap"
          cdk_stack: "aws:// ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCOUNT }}/us-east-1"
        env:
          AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
          AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
          AWS_DEFAULT_REGION: "us-east-1"

      - name: cdk synth
        uses: youyo/aws-cdk-github-actions@v2.1.1
        with:
          cdk_subcommand: "synth"
          working_dir: "./cdk"
        env:
          AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
          AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
          AWS_DEFAULT_REGION: "us-east-1"

      - name: cdk deploy
        uses: youyo/aws-cdk-github-actions@v2.1.1
        with:
          cdk_subcommand: "deploy"
          cdk_stack: "frontend-appName"
          cdk_args: "--require-approval never"
          working_dir: "./cdk"
          actions_comment: false
        env:
          AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
          AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
          AWS_DEFAULT_REGION: "us-east-1"
```

build is right now failing at

```
Install aws-cdk latest
Successful install aws-cdk latest
Run cdk bootstrap  "aws:// ***/us-east-1"
 ⏳  Bootstrapping environment aws:// ***/us-east-1...
 ❌  Environment aws:// ***/us-east-1 failed bootstrapping: Error: Need to perform AWS calls for account  ***, but the current credentials are for ***
    at SdkProvider.forEnvironment (/usr/lib/node_modules/aws-cdk/lib/api/aws-auth/sdk-provider.ts:184:60)
    at Function.lookup (/usr/lib/node_modules/aws-cdk/lib/api/bootstrap/deploy-bootstrap.ts:31:18)
    at Bootstrapper.modernBootstrap (/usr/lib/node_modules/aws-cdk/lib/api/bootstrap/bootstrap-environment.ts:81:21)
    at /usr/lib/node_modules/aws-cdk/lib/cdk-toolkit.ts:575:24
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
    at CdkToolkit.bootstrap (/usr/lib/node_modules/aws-cdk/lib/cdk-toolkit.ts:572:5)
    at initCommandLine (/usr/lib/node_modules/aws-cdk/lib/cli.ts:341:12)
```

I have added the extra step "cdk bootstrap" because previous runs had a failure stating the application was not bootstrapped

Can someone help me troubleshoot this? I am not sure my specific issue but feel like I am very close.

Comment: General advice independent of the credentials error: `cdk bootstrap` is a once-per-env step you probably want to carry out once, locally.  You can then remove the bootstrap step from your github action.  The synth step can also be removed.  `cdk deploy` always synths before deploy, making `cdk synth` redundant in your action.

Answer (score 1):

Your machine needs to have the access & secret keys of the account which you're trying to bootstrap, but it seems they're incorrectly configured.

I suggest log into the AWS account which you're trying to bootstrap and generate fresh secret & access keys for your user, and then configure AWS CLI your machine to use those keys.

[This article](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-quickstart.html) explains how to do the same, hope this helps.